# Как реализовать фильтр в блокноте?

Tags: java, android

Я хочу модернизировать блокнот и добавить в него поиск по заметкам через EditText .
Вот исходный код .
У меня не получается нужна помощь !

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:hint="Фильтр" />
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/notes_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_notes_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/no_notes"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

//

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NoteEventListener, Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Note> notes;
    private NotesAdapter adapter;
    private NotesDao dao;
    private MainActionModeCallback actionModeCallback;
    private int chackedCount = 0;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private SharedPreferences settings;
    public static final String THEME_Key = "app_theme";
    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES="notepad_settings";
    private int theme;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.exit)

                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                    {
                        finishAndRemoveTask();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        settings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        theme = settings.getInt(THEME_Key, R.style.AppTheme);
        setTheme(theme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        setupNavigation(savedInstanceState, toolbar);
        // init recyclerView
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.notes_list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // init fab Button
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: 13/05/2018  add new note
                onAddNewNote();
            }
        });

        dao = NotesDB.getInstance(this).notesDao();


    }

    private void setupNavigation(Bundle savedInstanceState, Toolbar toolbar) {

        // Navigation menu items
       // List<IDrawerItem> iDrawerItems = new ArrayList<>(); fix error : removed on materialdrawer 7.0.0
        List<IDrawerItem<?>> iDrawerItems = new ArrayList<>();
        iDrawerItems.add(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Заметки").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_note_black_24dp));

        // sticky DrawItems ; footer menu items

       // List<IDrawerItem> stockyItems = new ArrayList<>(); removed on materialdrawer 7.0.0
        List<IDrawerItem<?>> stockyItems = new ArrayList<>();

        SwitchDrawerItem switchDrawerItem = new SwitchDrawerItem()
                .withName("Темная тема")
                .withChecked(theme == R.style.AppTheme_Dark)
                .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_dark_theme)
                .withOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(IDrawerItem drawerItem, CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO: 02/10/2018 change to darck theme and save it to settings
                        if (isChecked) {
                            settings.edit().putInt(THEME_Key, R.style.AppTheme_Dark).apply();
                        } else {
                            settings.edit().putInt(THEME_Key, R.style.AppTheme).apply();
                        }

                        // recreate app or the activity // if it's not working follow this steps
                        // MainActivity.this.recreate();

                        // this lines means wi want to close the app and open it again to change theme
                        TaskStackBuilder.create(MainActivity.this)
                                .addNextIntent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class))
                                .addNextIntent(getIntent()).startActivities();
                    }
                });

        stockyItems.add(switchDrawerItem);

        // navigation menu header
        AccountHeader header = new AccountHeaderBuilder().withActivity(this)
                .addProfiles(new ProfileDrawerItem()
                        .withName("APK")
                        .withIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round))
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .withSelectionListEnabledForSingleProfile(false) // we need just one profile
                .build();

        // Navigation drawer
        new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this) // activity main
                .withToolbar(toolbar) // toolbar
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState) // saveInstance of activity
                .withDrawerItems(iDrawerItems) // menu items
                .withTranslucentNavigationBar(true)
                .withStickyDrawerItems(stockyItems) // footer items
                .withAccountHeader(header) // header of navigation
                //.withOnDrawerItemClickListener(this) // listener for menu items click
                .build();

    }

    private void loadNotes() {
        this.notes = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Note> list = dao.getNotes();// get All notes from DataBase
        this.notes.addAll(list);
        this.adapter = new NotesAdapter(this, this.notes);
        // set listener to adapter
        this.adapter.setListener(this);
        this.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        showEmptyView();
        // add swipe helper to recyclerView

        swipeToDeleteHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    /**
     * when no notes show msg in main_layout
     */
    private void showEmptyView() {
        if (notes.size() == 0) {
            this.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.empty_notes_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            this.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.empty_notes_view).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start EditNoteActivity.class for Create New Note
     */
    private void onAddNewNote() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, EditNoteActivity.class));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        loadNotes();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNoteClick(Note note) {
        // TODO: 22/07/2018  note clicked : edit note
        Intent edit = new Intent(this, EditNoteActivity.class);
        edit.putExtra(NOTE_EXTRA_Key, note.getId());
        startActivity(edit);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNoteLongClick(Note note) {
        // TODO: 22/07/2018 note long clicked : delete , share ..
        note.setChecked(true);
        chackedCount = 1;
        adapter.setMultiCheckMode(true);

        // set new listener to adapter intend off MainActivity listener that we have implement
        adapter.setListener(new NoteEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNoteClick(Note note) {
                note.setChecked(!note.isChecked()); // inverse selected
                if (note.isChecked())
                    chackedCount++;
                else chackedCount--;

                if (chackedCount > 1) {
                    actionModeCallback.changeShareItemVisible(false);
                } else actionModeCallback.changeShareItemVisible(true);

                if (chackedCount == 0) {
                    //  finish multi select mode wen checked count =0
                    actionModeCallback.getAction().finish();
                }

                actionModeCallback.setCount(chackedCount + "/" + notes.size());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNoteLongClick(Note note) {

            }
        });

        actionModeCallback = new MainActionModeCallback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_delete_notes)
                    onDeleteMultiNotes();
                else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_share_note)
                    onShareNote();

                actionMode.finish();
                return false;
            }

        };

        // start action mode
        startActionMode(actionModeCallback);
        // hide fab button
        fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        actionModeCallback.setCount(chackedCount + "/" + notes.size());
    }

    private void onShareNote() {
        // TODO: 22/07/2018  we need share just one Note not multi

        Note note = adapter.getCheckedNotes().get(0);
        // TODO: 22/07/2018 do your logic here to share note ; on social or something else
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        String notetext = note.getNoteText() + "\n\n Create on : " +
                NoteUtils.dateFromLong(note.getNoteDate()) + "\n  By :" +
                getString(R.string.app_name);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, notetext);
        startActivity(share);


    }

    private void onDeleteMultiNotes() {
        // TODO: 22/07/2018 delete multi notes

        List<Note> chackedNotes = adapter.getCheckedNotes();
        if (chackedNotes.size() != 0) {
            for (Note note : chackedNotes) {
                dao.deleteNote(note);
            }
            // refresh Notes
            loadNotes();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Заметки успешно удалены!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else Toast.makeText(this, "\n" + "Заметки не выбраны", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //adapter.setMultiCheckMode(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {
        super.onActionModeFinished(mode);

        adapter.setMultiCheckMode(false); // uncheck the notes
        adapter.setListener(this); // set back the old listener
        fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // swipe to right or to left te delete
    private ItemTouchHelper swipeToDeleteHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(
            new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                @Override
                public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                    // TODO: 28/09/2018 delete note when swipe

                    if (notes != null) {
                        // get swiped note
                        Note swipedNote = notes.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                        if (swipedNote != null) {
                            swipeToDelete(swipedNote, viewHolder);

                        }

                    }
                }
            });

    private void swipeToDelete(final Note swipedNote, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage("Удалить заметку?")
                .setPositiveButton("Удалить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // TODO: 28/09/2018 delete note
                        dao.deleteNote(swipedNote);
                        notes.remove(swipedNote);
                        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                        showEmptyView();

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // TODO: 28/09/2018  Undo swipe and restore swipedNote
                        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());


                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create().show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

//

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NoteHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Note> notes;
    private NoteEventListener listener;
    private boolean multiCheckMode = false;


    public NotesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Note> notes) {
        this.context = context;
        this.notes = notes;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.note_layout, parent, false);
        return new NoteHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NoteHolder holder, int position) {
        final Note note = getNote(position);
        if (note != null) {
            holder.noteText.setText(note.getNoteText());
            holder.noteDate.setText(NoteUtils.dateFromLong(note.getNoteDate()));
            // init note click event
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listener.onNoteClick(note);
                }
            });

            // init note long click
            holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    listener.onNoteLongClick(note);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // check checkBox if note selected
            if (multiCheckMode) {
                holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // show checkBox if multiMode on
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(note.isChecked());
            } else holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide checkBox if multiMode off


        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notes.size();
    }

    private Note getNote(int position) {
        return notes.get(position);
    }


    /**
     * get All checked notes
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    public List<Note> getCheckedNotes() {
        List<Note> checkedNotes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Note n : this.notes) {
            if (n.isChecked())
                checkedNotes.add(n);
        }

        return checkedNotes;
    }


    class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView noteText, noteDate;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        public NoteHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            noteDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_date);
            noteText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_text);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        }
    }


    public void setListener(NoteEventListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void setMultiCheckMode(boolean multiCheckMode) {
        this.multiCheckMode = multiCheckMode;
        if (!multiCheckMode)
            for (Note note : this.notes) {
                note.setChecked(false);
            }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

//

Вот так не получается

```
EditText theFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);


        theFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                (MainActivity.this).adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: а что хоть не получается? что у вас получилось и что именно вы хотите добавить, ооочень сложно помочь основываясь только на коде и на фразе `у меня не получается` :) Приведите пример того что не получается, укажите только тот код который относится к проблеме

Comment: Скорее сказать я не знаю как реализовать фильтр

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Я все-равно не очень понял что вы подразумеваете под фразой - `я не знаю как реализовать фильтр`. Можно понимать это под тремя вещами:

1. Вы не знаете как реализовать фильтрацию массива по вашему параметру
2. Вы не знаете как выгрузить отфильтрованное в виджет списка
3. 1 и 2 пункты вместе

С учетом того что вы не привели ваш класс-модель который вы грузите в адаптер, то я покажу на примере как можно отфильтровать массив. Имеется модель:

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String parent;


    public Student(String name, String age, String parent){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(String parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

мы формируем массив состоящий из объектов данного класса:

```
ArrayList<Student> arrayList = new ArrayList<Student>();
arrayList.add(new Student("Bob", "10", "Marta"));
arrayList.add(new Student("Steve", "10", "Bob"));
arrayList.add(new Student("Bob", "11", "Marta"));
arrayList.add(new Student("Peter", "10", "Tom"));
arrayList.add(new Student("Greg", "16", "Phillip"));
arrayList.add(new Student("Bob", "10", "Marta"));
```

и фильтруем данный массив:

```
List<Student> filteredList = arrayList.stream().filter(student -> student.getAge().equals("10")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

ну и дальше грузим в список то что отфильтровали:

```
// set listener to adapter
this.adapter.setListener(this);
this.recyclerView.setAdapter(new NotesAdapter(this, filteredList));
```

если у вас это поле для ввода:

```
EditText theFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

находится в пределах главной активности, то нет нужды вызывать метод из адаптера. Можно просто создать метод в главной активности который будет получать параметры для фильтрации и перезагружать список:

```
void filter(String parameter, ArrayList<Student> arrayList){
        List<Student> filteredList = arrayList.stream().filter(student -> student.getAge().equals("10")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        // set listener to adapter
        this.adapter.setListener(this);
        this.recyclerView.setAdapter(new NotesAdapter(this, filteredList));
        this.adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
    }
```

вроде как-то так :)